# Most optimal way to removing Duplicates in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to remove duplicates in spark dataframes by using dropDuplicates() on couple of columns. But job is getting hung due to lots of shuffling involved and data skew. I have used 5 cores and 30GB of memory to do this. Data on which I am performing dropDuplicates() is about 12 million rows.

Please suggest me the most optimal way to remove duplicates in spark, considering data skew and shuffling involved.

Answer (score 0):

Delete duplicate operations is an expensive operation as it compare values from one RDD to all other RDDs and tries to consolidate the results. Considering the size of your data results can time consuming.

I would recommend groupby transformation on the columns of your dataframe followed by commit action. This way only the consolidated results from your RDD will be compared with other RDD that too lazily and then you can request the result through any of the action like commit / show etc

```
transactions.groupBy("col1”,”col2").count.sort($"count".desc).show
```

Answer (score 0):

1. distance():

```html
df.select(['id', 'name']).distinct().show()
```

2. dropDuplicates()

```html
df.dropDuplicates(['id', 'name']).show()
```

dropDuplicates() is the way to go if you want to drop duplicates over a subset of columns, but at the same time you want to keep all the columns of the original structure.

Comment: are there any performance considerations to keep in mind here?